# How to share something over LinkedIn in android?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have an app in which I have a button that will share some text/url to LinkedIN.

I am not doing much, I am just encoding it in the URL and passing it as a intent to browser. Here is the URL i used -

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=google.com

http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http://google.com

this one works on a desktop but not on a mobile browser.

I learned from their [forum](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/share-article-script-does-not-work) that this does not work on mobile? So what's the workaround?

Comment: A linkedIN dev replied in the forum that you posted that their webservice doesn't support mobile browsers at this time. Honestly I doubt there is a way to make it work. My best guess though is use one of the 3rd party browsers that allow you to set your own User Agent string and set it for a desktop browser. But I suspect simply fooling the site into thinking you are viewing it from a desktop browser is not going to be enough to make it work.

Comment: What browser do you use? Have you try various browsers instead?

Comment: I've tried the default browser as well as the Opera Mini.

Comment: It's only been nine years, but I can confirm: Still no mobile support.